# Warranty claims count prediction

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, prediction, count-data

I have weekly data of number of warranty claims from week of manufacturing. I want to use this historical data and predict the number of claims that may arise in next few weeks.

I have read about count data models like Poisson regression and NB regression but they expect the counts in the range of 0~30 (is this correct?). In my case the claims can be of the range 0 to several thousands. What would be an ideal way to solve this problem?